# is Bluetooth BR/EDR same as bluetooth Classic

Tags: bluetooth

Many BLE devices have `BR/EDR Controller Mode - LE + BR/EDR Host Mode` in their Flags. Does this mean that this Device is also a classic Bluetooth device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BR/EDR is the technical term for what you call bluetooth classic.

With "in their Flags" you probably mean in the advertisement? This would mean that the device at least reports, that it also implements bluetooth classic, yes.